# User resizable and re-positional window on webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying for a few days to figure out the best way to do what I am looking for. I would like to have an element on my page that includes iframes, that is resizable and re-positional by the end user.  They would be able to resize it and reposition it at any time while the rest of the site behind remains usable

I have tried a few jquery plugins, but none seem to do what I am looking for.

I found a list of lightbox clones (http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) , but none do quite what I am looking for. Does anyone have any ideas for a plugin that could accomplish this?  I may just not be thinking of the right search terms and have hit a bit of a dead end.

Comment: Did you simply check [jquery-UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) possibilities ?

Comment: @EdenSource I did try the dialog box but it was not re-positional.  Looking at the demo you posted I am clearly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combination of jQuery UI [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) to achieve effect of "Window in Window"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#window')
    .resizable()
    .draggable();
});
```

```css
#window {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #454;
  border-top: 5px solid blue;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
#window input {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="window">
  <label>Your name:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>
  <br/>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that looks great, but for some reason it is not re-positional for me.  I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @JoelLewis maybe you set it's position to `relative` or `static`?

Comment: I do for the child elements, but not for the "window" element.

Comment: looks like it was inheriting some weirdness.  Got it working thank you!! Any tips on how to keep it from moving when the page scrolls?